# WordPress - MailPoet - have email address input and subscribe button on same row?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a WordPress MailPoet subscribe action into a WordPress landing page.

Using the MailPoet form designer...

- Can I put the email input and subscribe buttons on the same row?
- How can I then put this MailPoet form into a container in my landing page, so that it appears adjacent to other buttons?

TIA

Comment: Once you have added the form to your page, if you provide a link, someone will be able to look at the HTML structure and give you the CSS needed to make the input and button appear on the same row.  The way that you will add the form to your page will depend on your theme.  Is there documentation for MailPoet that you can consult?

Comment: Here's the page https://cadwcambria.wales/?page_id=154    Apart from wanting the email control and submit button on the same row, I'd like the submit button to have the same color as the 'Get involved' button

Comment: The button and input appear side-by-side (on the same row) to me.  Did you already solve that, or do you mean you want the input above the button?

Comment: Not sure how that happened.  Anyhow the background color and button color are wrong

Comment: Also solved it,  but I can't get the 'Get involved' and 'Subscribe' elements to line up vertically. Any suggestions?

Comment: button color CSS...
#mailpoet_form_2 .mailpoet_submit {
    background-color: #5cb85c;
}